# Php: detect single letter in a string surrounded by special characters

Tags: php, regex

Say i have these strings

```
tavern-o-fallon-new-york
cut-n-shoot-texas
cut-n-shoot-texas-at-o-fellon
```

I'd like to to detect all the occurrences of the -o-, or any other pattern, and convert to o'

so i can convert the string to

```
Tavern O'Fallon New York
Cut'N'Shoot Texas
Cut'N'Shoot Texas At O'Fellon
```

I believe i can use some array of common patterns like the O', 'N' etc..

Comment: `s/-(.)-/\1'/`? of cousre, that's going to bomb on `build-a-bear` -> `build a'bear`.

Comment: @MarcB thanks...yes...that can work, but say i have french or italian cities so it's not actually just one single letter?

Comment: then you probably don't want regexes, or at least, not one single regex. regexes are for REGULAR text. if your inputs are irregular, then you can't really use a REGULAR expression on them.

Comment: have you tried str_replace ?

Comment: @MarcB or for example Deville's, if i save deville-s, i need to setup my patterns right? how doe that work?

Comment: then maybe `-(.)-?`, to make the trailing dash optional.

Comment: @KA_lin duh...sometimes the right solution is the most simple one... i'll try that...havent thought about

Comment: You can also get  your desired result by `preg_replace('/-\S-/ix', ' O\'', $text)`
It will convert string "tavern-o-fallon-new-york" to `tavern O'fallon-new-york`

Answer (score 1):

I`d use str_replace:

```
$phrase = 'tavern-o-fallon-new-york
cut-n-shoot-texas
cut-n-shoot-texas-at-o-fellon';
$phrase = str_replace(array('-n-','o-','-'),array('`N`','O`',' '), $phrase);
echo ucwords($phrase);
```

Output:

```
Tavern O`fallon New York
Cut`N`shoot Texas
Cut`N`shoot Texas At O`fellon
```

**Edit:**

To fix the lowercase letters:

```
$phrase = str_replace(array('-n-','o-','-'),array('`N` ','O` ',' '), $phrase); // add an extra space after the quote;
$phrase = ucwords($phrase); //then ucfirst can do the job
$phrase = str_replace('` ','`', $phrase); //remove the extra space
echo $phrase;
```

Comment: People always get so caught up in regex they forget the simple stuff ;-)

Comment: I know the feeling :))